# Do I discard weaknesses when they are done?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

Does Roland Banks' weakness Cover Up get discarded when I've removed all 3 clue tokens from it, or do other weaknesses get discarded when they are done with the instructions on the card?  There is no mention of it so my thinking is that I do not have to discard it and potentially end up drawing it again once I've resolved a card such as Cover Up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weakness (or treachery) cards go to your discard after being completed. Page 20 of the RRG:

> When a treachery card is drawn by an investigator, that investigator
>   must resolve its effects. Then, place the card in its discard pile
>   unless otherwise instructed by the ability.

Further, on page 7 of the RRG (emphasis mine), pertaining to weaknesses that are enemies and can be defeated:

> if an enemy has damage equal to or higher than its health, it is
>   defeated and placed in the encounter discard pile **(or in its owner’s
>   discard pile if it is a weakness)**.

Non-enemy weaknesses specifically say on the card what to do with them. For example, Cover Up says:

> When you would discover 1 or more clues at your location: Discard that many clues from Cover Up instead.
>   Forced - When the game ends, if there are any clues on Cover Up: You suffer 1 mental trauma.

This means that Cover Up stays on the table (with no clues on it) until the end of the scenario.

In contrast, Daisy's weakness (the Necromonicon), says:

> ...if The Necronomicon has no horror on it, discard it.

Comment: So unless a weakness explicitly directs it to the discard, it stays, even if there is no game end check? Abandoned and alone causes 2 horror loss and the removal of all discarded cards but says nothing more, so this stays in my threat area until game end?

Comment: If it is an *asset*, it stays on the table. This prevents Cover Up from being shuffled back into your deck and drawn again.

Comment: However, Abandoned and Alone is an *event*, so it is played and then discarded. I'm not 100% sure the timing, but it is either the last card to go into the discard before you remove them from the game, OR is the first card in the discard after the wipe. Based upon the grim rule, I'd imagine it is the latter case.

Comment: I was correct: "Any time a player plays an event card, its costs are paid, its effects are resolved (or canceled), and the card is placed in its owner’s discard pile after those effects resolve (or are canceled)." So A&A can be drawn again, if you cycle through Wendy's entire deck.

Comment: Abandoned and Alone is a Treachery player card, not an event unless somewhere it's stated that these are a subtype of event cards.  As such, it should fall into the same behavior of cards like Cover Up and not be discarded.  After reading Necronomicon, this does sort of make sense as Abandoned and Alone seems more brutal than Necronomicon would be.

Comment: While you are correct that it is not an event (oops), it does still go to your discard, as that is actually the default for treachery cards: "When a treachery card is drawn by an investigator, that investigator must resolve its effects. Then, place the card in its discard pile unless otherwise instructed by the ability."

Comment: I've added the relevant text above.

Comment: The quoted text seems to definitively settle that Treachery cards should by default be discarded except when otherwise stated (like Cover Up stating to put it into the threat area).  Since not all weakness cards are Treachery and the quote applies to Treachery, it seems better to answer that *some* weaknesses go to discard (as described in the Treachery case) but some don't necessarily. I intentionally haven't looked through all the weaknesses so I can't cite other example cards, but your rule quote is great for Treachery cards.